# How to prevent focus from being removed from my editable div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I am trying to create a formatting bar for my editable div. But when I click on my formatting bar, the div is unfocused. How to stop this from happening using jQuery.
Regards,
Ahsan Naveed

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide is with the problematic code, as well as what steps you've taken to solve the problem yourself. However, always make sure that the code you post is pertinent to your question and constitutes a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<formatting bar>").click(function() {
    $("<editable div>").focus();
});
```

Comment: Already tried that. It does work, but it does not seem to be a good solution and also there is a noticeable blink seen when focus is switched among the two.